# Validate file upload without any entity

Tags: validation, symfony

I create a new form type in symfony "ImportType". This form type includes only two fields, a file input and a submit button.

In my controller i will validate the posted file. I will check the file mimetype and filesize. But how can i validate this without any entity?

If i use the validator service to validate, i do not how can i inject validation informations for mimetype and file size?

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

public function importAction(Request $request) 
{
    // Create new form and map this with the user object
    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.import'))->add('send', 'submit');

    // Handle user request
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $file = $form->get('attachment');

    $fileContraints = new File();
    $fileContraints->maxSizeMessage = 'msg.validator.file.import.maxFileSize';
    $fileContraints->mimeTypes      = 'msg.validator.file.import.mimeType';

     /** @todo set options for file mimetype and max file size **/
    $file = $form->get('attachment');

      // use the validator to validate the value
        $errorList = $this->get('validator')->validateValue(
            $file,
            $fileContraints
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate it in you controller and add an error manually:

```
$file = $form->get('attachment');

$fileContraints = new File();
$fileContraints->maxSizeMessage = 'msg.validator.file.import.maxFileSize';
$fileContraints->mimeTypes      = 'msg.validator.file.import.mimeType';

$errorList = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($file, $fileContraints);

if (count($errorList)) {
    $errorMessage = $errorList[0]->getMessage();
    $file->addError($errorMessage);

    // adding an error causes the form to be invalid:
    $form->isValid(); // now returns false
}
```

please note that the validator API changed in 2.5:

```
// pre 2.5
$errorList = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($file, $fileContraints);
// 2.5 and higher
$errorList = $this->get('validator')->validate($file, $fileContraints);
```

Comment: Ok and how can i define the mimetype that only a specified mime type is valid as example "txt" file.

Comment: This is a different question but: the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#mimetypes) can tell you, a string or array of allowed types

Comment: Many thanks i solve my problem with the following constructor options. new File(array('maxSize' => '2M', 'mimeTypes' => array("text/csv")));

Comment: getting "Expected argument of type "array or \Countable", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" given" done similarly as you, should be same.